# What does the enteredPassword = passwordEntry.get() command do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

What does the    enteredPassword = passwordEntry.get()    command do in this context:

```
import Tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

def checkPassword():
    password = "Oranges"
    enteredPassword = passwordEntry.get()
    if password == enteredPassword:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Correct")
    else:
        confirmLabel.config(text="Incorrect")

passwordLabel = tk.Label(window, text="Password:")
passwordEntry = tk.Entry(window, show="*")

button = tk.Button(window, text="Enter", command=checkPassword)
confirmLabel = tk.Label(window)

passwordLabel.pack()
passwordEntry.pack()
button.pack()
confirmLabel.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Thank you!

Comment: It gets the text stored in the `passwordEntry` widget (a text entry field) and stores it in the variable named `enteredPassword`.

Answer (score 2):

`passwordEntry` is a `Tkinter.Entry` object. The [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/entry.html) states:

> .get()
>
> Returns the entry's current text as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm, you'll see that the `.get()` method returns the current text in a Tkinter Entry widget.

However, that is not usually the best way to interact with an Entry widget. Typically the best way is to assign a Tkinter.StringVar to the widget via the textvariable keyword, and then you can `.get()` and `.set()` the StringVar, and the text that you write to the StringVar will appear in the Entry's text area. But more importantly than this, you can set a 'trace' function on the StringVar which executes a callback function anytime you change the value of the StringVar, such as using the `StringVar.set()` method or by someone typing in some text in the Entry widget.  Powerful stuff!